# How to display the selected country name from slicer when there is no data for the selected month and the selected country in power BI with the DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the `Country` and `Date` columns.

[image: Table]

I have a slicer with `Country` and `Date`, now as I select the slicers for `UK` and `May-21`, it shows blank as the data is not there for `May-21`.

[image: Blank Output]

Now I always want to display the selected country whether there is data or not. I tried creating a measure using DAX, `REMOVEFILTERS`, and many other things but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code :

```
SELECTED COUNTRY = 
var __coutries = CALCULATETABLE(values('your table name'[Country]), ALLEXCEPT('your table name','your table name'[Country]))
RETURN 
    IF(COUNTROWS(__coutries) == 1, __coutries, "")
```

[this article reveals how to manage the familly of allxxx functions.](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/)